# Cosa differenzia "inebriarsi" da "ubriacarsi"?

Tags: word-usage

Inebriare: (v. tr.): (Diz.Hoepli)

> - Rendere ebbro, ubriacare: un bicchiere di vino basta a inebriarlo
> - fig. Produrre uno stato di eccitazione, di esaltazione: il Profumo lo inebriava.

(v. intr.) pronom. Inebriàrsi:

> - Diventare ebbro, ubriacarsi: inebriarsi di vino, di liquori.
> - fig. Provare un senso di eccitazione, di esaltazione o di commozione: a quel dolce canto s'inebriava

Inebriare o inebriarsi sono sinonimi di ubriacare o ubriacarsi. Penso  che inebriare/inebriarsi siano usati soprattutto in senso figurato, mentre in senso fisico si usi maggiormente ubriacare/ubriacarsi. È corretta questa mia impressione? O forse l'uso nei due significati dipende da fattori storici o geografici?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Direi di sì: inebriarsi (da cui "ubriacarsi" deriva) è una voce più aulica. Si potrebbe usare per le bevute di Noè, o di D'Annunzio. Oggi è usata soprattutto in senso figurato; direi che usata in senso fisico richiama comunque gli aspetti psicologici della alterazione alcolica (eccitazione esaltazione ecc). Oppure naturalmente, potrebbe essere usata invece di "ubriacarsi" con intento ironico. Notare anche l'uso nel linguaggio giuridico: "guida in stato di ebbrezza".

Comment: Confermo che l'uso contemporaneo è quasi esclusivamente figurato: una rapida occhiata a campione di “inebriato” su Google Books, restringendosi per esempio al Novecento (http://tinyurl.com/m7wpmdy), mostra praticamente solo persone inebriate da sentimenti, sensazioni, grazie divine e simili.

Comment: @DaG - concordo in pieno...una differenza sostanziale a mio parere che i vari dizionari sembrano non cogliere.

Answer (score 2):

A me sembra che dal punto di vista dell'uso proprio/figurato i due vocaboli "inebriare" ed "ubriacare" siano più o meno equivalenti. Per me la differenza principale sta nel fatto che "inebriare" è più leggero di "ubriacare". Una persona "inebriata" non è del tutto lucida, ma diciamo che può camminare. Una persona "ubriaca" è completamente incapace di fare qualsiasi cosa.

Al di là di questo, come indica Pietro Majer, "inebriare" è un pochino più aulico. Nel parlato, per indicare lo stesso significato, io userei "alticcio", "allegro" o "brillo".

Answer (score 0):

Il senso e l'affinità, così come il significato, dipende da come vengono percepite le parole, producono effetti determinati. Secondo il contesto, possono fare allusione all'estasi dei sensi, qualcosa d'involontario anche se provocato da qualcosa che ci influenza, oppure può essere uno stato provocato al cui si finisce per cedere, al superare i limiti arrivando all'incoscienza alterando anche i sensi, la visione e l'equilibrio, appunto dal consumo di alcol. È comunque e sempre, ad ogni modo e senza dubbio, sia in senso stretto o figurato, un'esperienza ambigua.

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie @Charo♦ .